# Difficulty loading a texture and passing it to a class in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, argument-passing

This is an assignment for a c#/XNA 4.0 class, and no, I'm not a HWgrade-zombie. I'd let you know the circumstances for my asking about this, the amount of "research" I've done, and that I wish to learn rather than get a grade, but it'd be considered fluff and deleted.

Anyhow, the problem I'm having is that my content (a sprite sheet) which I'm trying to load into "textureImage" in Game1.cs, which is then passed to "Sprite.cs" to be drawn, via "userControlledSprite.cs", isn't being drawn when I compile my program. Being new to c# and XNA both, I understand the issue (that the content loads, but isn't passed correctly), but I'm lost regarding a way to address it.

Here are the full three classes that my program consists of:

Game1.cs -- Calls the userControlledSprite.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

    namespace Proj06
    {
        public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
        {
           GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
           SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

            static Texture2D textureImage;
            static Point frameSize = new Point(52,50);
            static Point currentFrame = new Point(0, 0);
            static Point sheetSize = new Point(4, 1);
            static Vector2 position = Vector2.Zero;
            static int collisionOffset = 1;
            static Vector2 speed;

           userControlledSprite UserControlledSprite1;


        public Game1()
        {
           graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
           Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
           base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            textureImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"images/Picture");
            UserControlledSprite1 = new userControlledSprite(textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame, sheetSize, speed);
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
          /// Ignore this void
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
            UserControlledSprite1.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Sprite.cs -- Draws and animates the sprite, as well as checks for collisions.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

    namespace Proj06
    {
       abstract class Sprite
        {
            Texture2D textureImage;
            protected Point frameSize;
            Point currentFrame;
            Point sheetSize;
            int collisionOffset;
            int timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
            int millisecondsPerFrame;
            const int defaultMillisecondsPerFrame = 16;
            protected Vector2 speed;
            protected Vector2 position;

            public Sprite(Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position, Point frameSize,
                int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize, Vector2 speed)
                : this(textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame,
                sheetSize, speed, defaultMillisecondsPerFrame)
            {
            }

            public Sprite(Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position, Point frameSize,
                int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize, Vector2 speed,
                int millisecondsPerFrame)
            {
                this.textureImage = textureImage;
                this.position = position;
                this.frameSize = frameSize;
                this.collisionOffset = collisionOffset;
                this.currentFrame = currentFrame;
                this.sheetSize = sheetSize;
                this.speed = speed;
                this.millisecondsPerFrame = millisecondsPerFrame;
            }

            public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
            {
                timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame)
                {
                    timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
                    ++currentFrame.X;
                    if (currentFrame.X >= sheetSize.X)
                    {
                        currentFrame.X = 0;
                        ++currentFrame.Y;
                        if (currentFrame.Y >= sheetSize.Y)
                        {
                            currentFrame.Y = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin();

                spriteBatch.Draw(textureImage,
                    position,
                    new Rectangle(currentFrame.X * frameSize.X,
                        currentFrame.Y * frameSize.Y,
                        frameSize.X, frameSize.Y),
                        Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero,
                        1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

                spriteBatch.End();
            }

            public abstract Vector2 direction
            {
                get;
            }

            public Rectangle collisionRect
            {
                get
                {
                    return new Rectangle(
                        (int)position.X + collisionOffset,
                        (int)position.Y + collisionOffset,
                        frameSize.X - (collisionOffset * 2),
                        frameSize.Y - (collisionOffset * 2));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and userControlledSprite.cs -- deals with the sprite's movement and position

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


    namespace Proj06
    {
        class userControlledSprite : Sprite
        {
            public userControlledSprite(Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position,
                Point frameSize, int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize,
                Vector2 speed)
                : base(textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame,
                sheetSize, speed)
            {
            }

            public userControlledSprite(Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position,
                Point frameSize, int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize,
                Vector2 speed, int millisecondsPerFrame)
                : base(textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame,
                sheetSize, speed, millisecondsPerFrame)
            {
            }

            public override Vector2 direction
            {
                get
                {
                    Vector2 inputDirection = Vector2.Zero;

                    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                        inputDirection.X -= 1;
                    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                        inputDirection.X += 1;
                    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                        inputDirection.Y -= 1;
                    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                        inputDirection.Y += 1;

                    return inputDirection * speed;
                }
            }

            public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
            {
                position += direction;

                if (position.X < 0)
                    position.X = 0;
                if (position.Y < 0)
                    position.Y = 0;
                if (position.X > clientBounds.Width - frameSize.X)
                    position.X = clientBounds.Width - frameSize.X;
                if (position.Y > clientBounds.Height - frameSize.Y)
                    position.X = clientBounds.Height - frameSize.Y;

                base.Update(gameTime, clientBounds);
            }
        }
    }
```

I will continue searching online for any helpful resources, and will post edits if I find anything. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're not calling the draw method from your Game1 class and Sprite is not extending DrawableGameComponent (and then added to Game.Components) to register your overriden draw methods either. You need to do at least one of those things. It also looks like you're missing the  spriteBatch.Begin and spriteBatch.End calls. Set a breakpoint in your Draw/Update methods to see if they're called.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the field definition for UserControlledSprite1 where it is, but don't initialize it there:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    userControlledSprite UserControlledSprite1;
}
```

Then initialize it in the `LoadContent()` method right after loading the texture:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    textureImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"images/Picture");
    UserControlledSprite1 = new userControlledSprite(textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame, sheetSize, speed);
}
```

Also, make sure you're calling the `UserControlledSprite1.Draw()` method in `Game1.Draw()`.

Comment: I edited my code as you suggested, as well as put in gameTime and spriteBatch as the arguments for the UserControlledSprite1.Draw() method, and have received the following error:                  Field 'Proj06.Game1.UserControlledSprite1' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Comment: @Newprgm Make sure you add that last line that I added above to your `LoadContent()` method.

Comment: @Newprgm You still need to call `UserControlledSprite1.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch)` in `Game1.Draw()` right after the line `GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);`

Comment: The problem is still up to date (just forgot to add that portion in editing the post).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple here, your `Draw` and `Update` methods are never called.

If you want them to be called automatically by XNA, your `Sprite` class needs to extend `DrawableGameComponent` and be registered within `Game1`. For that, you'll need to pass `Game` as an argument. The `Draw` method you'll override will also need a `SpriteBatch`, so pass it in the constructor too. It's not really a clean way to do it, but it will work. Then call `Components.Add` on each `DrawableGameComponent` you have.

Once that's done, simply call spriteBatch.Begin() and spriteBatch.End() in Game1 (to do only one call on Begin and End), each Sprite will then draw itself.

I also took the liberty to remove useless `using`s and fix your class names to fit C# conventions (PascalCase).

The important parts that changed are :

- userControlledSprite now receives the spriteBatch and Game class
- userControlledSprite is registered as a component
- Sprite now extends DrawableGameComponent
- spriteBatch.Begin and End are now called
- Sprite now overrides the correct Draw method.

**Please note I've left your Update method unchanged.** It will not be called unless you change it for `public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)`.

If you set a breakpoint in Draw, it should be called by XNA.

Game1.cs

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Proj06
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        private Texture2D textureImage;
        private Point frameSize = new Point(52, 50);
        private Point currentFrame = new Point(0, 0);
        private Point sheetSize = new Point(4, 1);
        private Vector2 position = Vector2.Zero;
        private int collisionOffset = 1;
        private Vector2 speed;

        private UserControlledSprite userControlledSprite1;


        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            textureImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"images/Picture");
            userControlledSprite1 = new UserControlledSprite(this, spriteBatch, textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame, sheetSize, speed);
            Components.Add(userControlledSprite1);
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                Exit();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
}
```

UserControlledSprite.cs

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


namespace Proj06
{
    class UserControlledSprite : Sprite
    {
        public UserControlledSprite(Game game, SpriteBatch sb, Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position,
            Point frameSize, int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize,
            Vector2 speed)
            : base(game, sb, textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame,
            sheetSize, speed)
        {
        }

        public UserControlledSprite(Game game, SpriteBatch sb, Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position,
            Point frameSize, int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize,
            Vector2 speed, int millisecondsPerFrame)
            : base(game, sb, textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame,
            sheetSize, speed, millisecondsPerFrame)
        {
        }

        public override Vector2 direction
        {
            get
            {
                Vector2 inputDirection = Vector2.Zero;

                if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                    inputDirection.X -= 1;
                if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                    inputDirection.X += 1;
                if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                    inputDirection.Y -= 1;
                if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                    inputDirection.Y += 1;

                return inputDirection * speed;
            }
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
        {
            position += direction;

            if (position.X < 0)
                position.X = 0;
            if (position.Y < 0)
                position.Y = 0;
            if (position.X > clientBounds.Width - frameSize.X)
                position.X = clientBounds.Width - frameSize.X;
            if (position.Y > clientBounds.Height - frameSize.Y)
                position.X = clientBounds.Height - frameSize.Y;

            base.Update(gameTime, clientBounds);
        }
    }
}
```

Sprite.cs

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Proj06
{
    abstract class Sprite : DrawableGameComponent
    {
        Texture2D textureImage;
        protected Point frameSize;
        Point currentFrame;
        Point sheetSize;
        int collisionOffset;
        int timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
        int millisecondsPerFrame;
        const int defaultMillisecondsPerFrame = 16;
        protected Vector2 speed;
        protected Vector2 position;
        private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public Sprite(Game game, SpriteBatch sb, Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position, Point frameSize,
            int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize, Vector2 speed)
            : this(game, sb, textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame,
            sheetSize, speed, defaultMillisecondsPerFrame)
        {
        }

        public Sprite(Game game, SpriteBatch sb, Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position, Point frameSize,
            int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize, Vector2 speed,
            int millisecondsPerFrame) : base(game)
        {
            this.textureImage = textureImage;
            this.position = position;
            this.frameSize = frameSize;
            this.collisionOffset = collisionOffset;
            this.currentFrame = currentFrame;
            this.sheetSize = sheetSize;
            this.speed = speed;
            this.millisecondsPerFrame = millisecondsPerFrame;
            spriteBatch = sb;
        }

        public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
        {
            timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame)
            {
                timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
                ++currentFrame.X;
                if (currentFrame.X >= sheetSize.X)
                {
                    currentFrame.X = 0;
                    ++currentFrame.Y;
                    if (currentFrame.Y >= sheetSize.Y)
                    {
                        currentFrame.Y = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(textureImage,
                position,
                new Rectangle(currentFrame.X * frameSize.X,
                    currentFrame.Y * frameSize.Y,
                    frameSize.X, frameSize.Y),
                    Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero,
                    1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        public abstract Vector2 direction
        {
            get;
        }

        public Rectangle collisionRect
        {
            get
            {
                return new Rectangle(
                    (int)position.X + collisionOffset,
                    (int)position.Y + collisionOffset,
                    frameSize.X - (collisionOffset * 2),
                    frameSize.Y - (collisionOffset * 2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

As an addendum, I'd strongly suggest you move to MonoGame. XNA is not supported anymore (It was killed off by Microsoft a long time ago) and MonoGame is the open source implementation. Not much have changed, but you'll still need to use XNA's content pipeline (the .XNB files).

If you want to stick to XNA, start projects with the [Platformer Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx). You will better see how XNA works, as your architecture is quite weird.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding what you meant by changing the update method, but I tried changing the update method into a "public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)" instead of a "protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime" and got "cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member". And thanks for the suggestion. I'm taking this class to see if I may want to go into video game programming, but it's not been as fruitful as I'd hoped (in the sense of practical knowledge).

Comment: @Newprgm The update method problem is with the Rectangle parameter you are using. XNA's default update method does not use it, so there's a clash between that and `UserControlledSprite` update.. For more info about game programming there's always [GameDev StackExchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) website. But depending on where you'll work, you won't always start from scratch like XNA does. Usually the companies use an homemade engine or they buy the licenses for one (Ex: Unity or CryEngine). However most gamedev workplaces sadly share the "lot of hours" and "low pay" characteristics.

Comment: And don't forget to take a look at the [Starter Kits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) (even though they're on XNA3.1) and various [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) where Draw and Update methods are well described.